# Redux useSelector does not infer state properly --- Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Would love to know how to infer my state on the `useSelector` hook

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    
    import { reducers } from './reducers';
    
    export const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk));
    
    export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducers>;
```

Want to use it in my component like so

```
const { LogoutUser } = bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
const appState = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);

{appState.isAuthenticated && (
              <Button
                onClick={handleUserLogout}
                size={'sm'}
                colorScheme={'red'}
              >
                Logout
              </Button>
            )}
```

Typescript is annoyed

```
 Error Property 'isAuthenticated' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

My State = Istate

```
export interface IState {
  user: IUser | null;
  isAuthenticated: false;
}
```

My Reducer

```
import { IState} from '../../interfaces';
import { AuthAction } from '../actionsTypes';
import { initialState } from '../state';
import { AuthActionTypes } from '../types';

export const AuthReducer = (
  state: IState| undefined = initialState,
  action: AuthAction
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AuthActionTypes.LOGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    case AuthActionTypes.LOGOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My root reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { AuthReducer } from './AuthReducer';

export const reducers = combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer,
});

export type State = ReturnType<typeof reducers>;
```

Comment: Can you show IState type please ?

Comment: Please the question again

Comment: Thanks have you try to follow how to types `useSelector` ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73139002/7618742

Comment: Can you also show your `reducers` please ?

Comment: And root reducer too

Comment: Are you using redux-toolkit ? or did you add `@types/react-redux` ?

Comment: Not implementing redux-toolkit

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to create your own `useSelector` and `useDispatch` types ?

```js
// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

Have you try to generate `RootState` from `store.getState` ?

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

Have you try to configure your store with `configureStore` ?

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducers
});
```

Comment: I think this is what is recommended [in the docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript) as well

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: This does not work

Comment: Can you show a reproductible example ? with codesandbox for example

Comment: Have you try to use `configureStore` instead of create store ?

Comment: It uses pure redux, not redux-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

When your app is loaded, `appState` is `null`.
So in this case `isAuthenticated` property doesn't exist.
Therefore, you need to use `?` before `.` to determine null object.

```js
const { LogoutUser } = bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
const appState = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);

{appState?.isAuthenticated && (
              <Button
                onClick={handleUserLogout}
                size={'sm'}
                colorScheme={'red'}
              >
                Logout
              </Button>
            )}
```